# Write JSON txt query to file in r

Tags: r, json

```
query<-'{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Region",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "3010",
          "4020"          
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Sex",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "1",
          "2"
        ]
      }
 }
    
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "json-stat2"
  }
}'
```

Now - how can I write the query string to file and retrieve it. So far I've tried `writelines`, `save` etc, but I retrieve multiple strings rather than one long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have "\n" in your string, which forces new lines in your saved file, and then when you read it you will get multiple string. One option is to read it and then collapse it

```
paste0(readLines("abc.txt"),collapse="")
```

another is to deal away with the nuisances when writing the file, then you will get only one string

```
writeLines(gsub('"',"'",gsub("\n| ","",query)),"abc.txt")
```